# CSS align next to each other and annoying border that should apply to one div only

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with aligning CSS, they won't align next to each other, and one is below the other, not in line. This is the issue:

http://postimage.org/image/pgo4oy09p/

I've used a certain tutorial, and this is the CSS code I have:

```
div.Outer {
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}

div.InnerLeft {
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background: #CCCCCC;        
    float: left;
    border: none;
}

div.InnerRight {
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    background: #AAAAFF;        
    float: right;
    border: none;
}
```

This is my HTML code that defines the divs, as well as jQuery tabs...

```
<div class="usual"> 
  <ul class="idTabs"> 
    <li><a href="#idTab1" class="selected">Liverpool</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#idTab2">London Gatwick</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#idTab3">Katowice</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#idTab4">Glasgow</a></li> 
  </ul> 

    <div id="idTab1">

    <div id="header_operations">Liverpool, England (EGGP/LPL)</div>
    <div class="Outer">
        <div class="InnerLeft"></div>

    <div class="InnerRight">
    <p>Liverpool John Lennon Airport is an international airport serving the city of Liverpool and the North West of England. Formerly known as Speke Airport, RAF Speke, and Liverpool Airport the airport is located within the City of Liverpool adjacent to the estuary of the River Mersey some 6.5 NM (12.0 km; 7.5 mi) southeast of the centre of Liverpool, the airport is named after Liverpudlian musician John Lennon. Alongside domestic services, there are regular scheduled flights to dozens of locations across Europe, the Near East and North Africa.</p>
    <p>Between 1997 and 2007 it was one of Europe's fastest growing airports, having increased its annual passenger numbers from 689,468 in 1997 to 5.47 million in 2007. Over 5.2 million passengers passed through the airport in 2011, making it the tenth busiest airport in the United Kingdom. Liverpool Airport has a CAA Public Use Aerodrome Licence (Number P735) that allows flights for the public transport of passengers and for flying instruction.</p>
    </div>

    </div>  
    </div>

    <div id="idTab2">

    <div id="header_operations">London Gatwick, England (EGKK/LGW)</div>
    <div class="hubairport_box" style="margin-left: 265px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;">
    <p>Stuff here.</p>
    </div>
    </div> 

  <div id="idTab3">  

  <div id="header_operations">Katowice, Poland (EPKT/KTW)</div>

  <div class="hubairport_box" style="margin-left: 265px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;">
  <p> Description </p>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div id="idTab4">  

  <div id="header_operations">Glasgow International, Scotland (EGPF/GLA)</div>
  <div class="hubairport_box" style="margin-left: 265px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;">
  <p>blablabla...</p>
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

As you may see on the screen, I also have trouble with the border, and I've been tearing my hair out to try and get rid of it, the only thing that made it disappear was border: none defined in the HTML code. I tried in the CSS, and it just stays there. I've defined it under .usual, and I was hoping it would stay only there, and not apply to the divs inside div class="usual". Any help would be appreciated.

P.S - I've added the full CSS code upon request in the comments below...

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Okay from the code you have posted, i see that you are missing three </div> closing tabs, dit you ommit it in the post or does it not exist in the code

Comment: I'm 100% positive that they're all closed. Checked every div tag to make sure that they're not open.

Comment: Thats odd because the post you coded needs three closing div tags, can you update your post with all the code of the html page?

Comment: Sure, I'll add it straight away.

Comment: So far from what i have seen is that you should change all the `id="header_operations"` to `class="header_operations"` but dont know if that will help. This is just a good practice

Comment: it would be always nice to put some jsfiddle or working problem so we can do this on the fly..right now its kind of hard to guess and put solution for the same..

Comment: I just built up what you submitted. Everything seems normal if I put a clearing div at the end of Outer and put a &nbsp; inside of InnerLeft. It still doesn't look even close to your screenshot though because we're lacking a lot of CSS / JS?

Comment: Could you please submit all of the code? Preferrably on JSFiddle, the 3 css classes provided dont show what the error is.

Comment: @HighFlyerPL185 hello - dear can you please put your whole css so i can solve your prob ASAP.

Comment: check my answer and let me know is it what you want or some thing else.. i just made the fiddle based on your code.

Comment: Here you go :) http://pastebin.com/xgi9b6cL

Comment: See my updated fiddle and demo for updated answer based on your css provided in pastebin.com

Comment: ohh i forgot to ask you on which div you want border.. please let me know. and i have change little bit css so you can see changes in fiddle.

Comment: I want the border just below the tabs, so I guess that's the .usual div. Thank you.

Comment: Additionally, I have noticed that .usual div should not be that but .usual, because I have another .usual define which is the outside box. Now in theory, as I've tested, .usual div sets the settings for every DIV inside .usual - if you understand me. So I got it working by changing it to .usual. Now the borders are gone but the tabs are slightly lower, how would I move them back up?

Comment: can you upload it somewhere if it's not so private?

Comment: possibly you will miss `clear:both` and `Position:relative`

Comment: No change. I found that if I remove clear:both from .usual div, it works, but the top menu overflows the blue header I've made. Plus the div.Outer is for some reason outside the tab :(

Comment: I made a Fiddle of your code. http://jsfiddle.net/vUTwD/ What specifically are the issues?

Comment: Mainly, the boxes inside the tab should be aligned left and right, one however is below the other by the looks of it. The div.Outer is also outside the tab for some reason, and it should be inside idTab

Answer (score 0):

As per code and css provided by you and what i understand by reading and seeing your problem in image and if i am getting your problem correct then see the below fiddle(demo) for solution.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AxCCf/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AxCCf/embedded/result/

**UPDATED FIDDLE**  Based on your provided css on pastebin.com

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AxCCf/2/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AxCCf/2/embedded/result/

Comment: I noticed that every DIV inside the idTab1 box or any other box from 1-4 has the attributes picked up from div.usual, i.e the borders. The fiddle thing gives me the following result: http://postimage.org/image/ggf1233sr/